# Problems running websphere application server for developers

Tags: websphere

I've just installed Websphere application server for developers version 8.5.5.9, using IBM installation manager. When I try and create a profile I get an error that points me to a log file. Here's the beginning of it:

```
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.6 Windows 7 amd64-64 Compressed References 20151222_283040 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
```

J9VM - R26_Java626_SR8_20151222_1616_B283040
JIT  - tr.r11_20151209_107111.01
GC   - R26_Java626_SR8_20151222_1616_B283040_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20151222_283040
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.101
!MESSAGE Product com.ibm.ws.pmt.views.standalone.standAloneWasTools could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.146
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.146
!MESSAGE Bundle websphere@plugins\com.ibm.ws.pmt.views_8.5.1.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.ibm.ws.pmt.views 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.146
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.ws.profile.utils_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.ibm.ws.pmt.views 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.146
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.ws.profile_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.ibm.ws.pmt.views 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.146
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.ws.wct.config.definitionLocations_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.ibm.ws.pmt.views 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.146
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.logging_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.ibm.ws.pmt.views 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.146
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.ws.wct.config.definitions_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.ibm.ws.pmt.views 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.146
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.wsspi.profile.registry_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.ibm.ws.pmt.views 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.146
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.wsspi.profile_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.147
!MESSAGE Bundle websphere@plugins\com.ibm.ws.pmt.tools_8.0.0.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 com.ibm.ws.pmt.tools 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.147
!MESSAGE Missing imported package com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.logging_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-07-27 11:53:16.147
!MESSAGE Bundle websphere@plugins\com.ibm.ws.pmt.views.standalone_8.0.0.jar was not resolved.
```

Cleary there are some missing jar files, but I have no idea why they weren't installed or were to get them from. 
Should also mention that I'm completely new to Websphere.

Comment: When you say "when I run it", do you mean when you try to start the server or create a profile?  The PMT classes mentioned in the above stack are used to create a profile after installation and should have been installed by IM.  What platform is this?  Were there any errors from IM during install?

Comment: Sorry, I meant creating a profile, I'll reword. No errors during the installation process.

Comment: did you check if these jars exist on your system? Also check the installation logs, as it looks like broken install to me. What platform are you using? Did you use same user for install and profile creation?

Comment: The jars don't appear to be on my system, but I have no idea where to get them. I get zero google results for most of them. 
The install looked fine, last message in the postinstall log is this one "All config actions ran successfully with return code 0".
I've used the same user for both install and profile creation. I'll try again but install as administrator.
I'm using windows 7

Comment: Install as admin and NOT to Program files folder but something simpler like c:\IBM\WebSphere

Comment: I tried as admin with no luck, I'll try again as admin under a different directory.

Comment: Just tried again as admin in a different directory. No luck I'm afraid.

Comment: Is there some extra dependency I need to install first outside of the application manager? From the instructions on IBM's website it looks like this should be fairly simple to install.

Comment: No, IM should take care of all dependencies, you don't need to install anything additional.

Comment: I just installed 8.5.5.9 Developers Edition from scratch on Win7 and created a new profile with no problems.  From where are you getting your installation image?

Comment: I've added the following repository http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V85WASDeveloperILAN

Comment: @wybourn did you find a solution? I am now also getting this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Just resorted to using Tomcat locally.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue, but found the solution (at least for me).

What I found was that my computer was imaged with @user.home pointing to a UNC, which webshpere does not like.  (see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21584343).  When I got the error, a dialog was even displayed showing the location of the error log with a UNC name.

As shown in the ibm link I placed in the previous paragraph, to resolve i simply located my config.ini (in my case, C:\Program_Files 
(x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\ProfileManagement\eclipse64\configuration) and changed @user.home to c\:/temp in the following 2 keys:

```
 •  osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/AppData/Lo . . .

 •  osgi.configuration.area=@user.home/AppData/Lo . . .
```

Hope this helps!
G